# NSData subStringFromIndex: Equivalent

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, trim

I'm receiving a stream of NSData characters with around at least 50 characters. Usually, I would try and convert this to an NSString and use the `subStringFromIndex:` selector, but it seems like NSString is NULL terminating (correct me if I'm wrong) and I'd rather skip the data / string conversion. Does anyone know if there is a way to get the charecter at specific index in NSData? For example, say that the data returned is:

```
<12345678 9abcdefg hjiklmno>
```

Lets say I would like to get the 7 and the 8 out, and just those two alone. To get the 7 and 8, I've looked into trying something like this:

```
NSData *dataTrimmed = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(7, -19)];
```

Works like a charm. But the issue is, the stream is always going to be a different length. It could be 100 characters or it could be 50, but I always know that the two values I need are located at the 42nd and 43rd spot. Does anyone have an example of or know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder that your code with a *negative length* does not crash.

To get the two bytes at position 42, 43, just use

```
NSData *dataTrimmed = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(42, 2)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Yeah I put a couple conditionals in there to prevent a crash, but it certainly was before those! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to skip the conversion to NSString?

The string you receive is encoded as NSData. Depending on the encoding each character will be represented as one or multiple bytes. If it is UTF8 encoded, some characters will be represented as one byte while other characters will be represented by two or more bytes.

For this reason, if you want your code be robust and handle different encodings and different string content you should first convert your NSData to a NSString and then index the string.

If your string is UTF-8 encoded you could do the following:

```
NSData *data = ...
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *subString = [str substringFromIndex:...
```

In my view, it only makes sense to skip converting to NSString if you receive a lot of data and you control both encoding and the contents of the string data you receive.

As the saying goes: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Great points man, thanks a lot for the input. Let me give this a shot real quick...